# How to update the small content of a mongodb field using updateMany and replace method?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation

Here's the example

```
{
  name:"John",
  emailId:"johncoderq@gmail.com"
}
```

And I wanted to change the emailId to johncoder@gmail.com .
Here I want to update this record by querying with regex and update using replace method.

Comment: Why not just query with the email which is much easier? Only use regex when the value is with the pattern.

Comment: I need to update multiple records at a time in which the regex is present